# I am not able to run this trigger on contacts related to accounts

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger

what i am trying to do is make a trigger on contact in which field **`acc_number__c`** is updated in Contact from the account field `acc_number__c` if the checkbox field `final_number__c` is selected in the contact object.
after reading about after and before triggers, what i came to understand is to use before if i only need to validate the field values that user inserts and when fields that are from the trigger object needs to be updated.
and to use after when i need to insert or update fields for other object.

So based on that i choose before , but ultimately did on both, the problem is it is working on the after trigger but i can't seem to think the right logic for before trigger.

```
    trigger Accnumberupdate3 on contact (before insert ,before update) {


            list<account> con = new list<account>();
             Set <id> ids = new set<id>();

              for( contact c : trigger.new){
              if(c.Finalize_Number__c == true){
               ids.add(c.accountId);}
       } 
           con = [select acc_number__c,id from account where id in :ids];

            contact c = new contact();
            for(account acc : con){

            if(c.Finalize_Number__c == true){

                c.Acc_Number__c = acc.acc_number__c;

                    }

             }




}
```

no error is shown but the field does not get updated

the after trigger for this works though

```
trigger Accnumberupdate2 on contact (after insert ) {

            list<contact> conlist = new list<contact>();
            list<contact> con = new list<contact>();
           Set <id> ids = new set<id>();
       for(contact c : trigger.new){
              if(c.Finalize_Number__c == true){
                system.debug('If condition');
                ids.add(c.Id);
                              }
       }
            con = [select acc_number__c,finalize_number__c,account.acc_number__c from contact where id 
                    in :ids];


        for(contact c : con){

                c.Acc_Number__c = c.account.acc_number__c;
                conlist.add(c);


             }


 update conlist;   

}
```

What am i doing wrong, also spare me please if I did a silly mistake, i am just 2 weeks old into this.

Thank you,
Nitin

Comment: As a tip you don't need to compare boolean variables on if statements you can directly type  if(c.Finalize_Number__c) to evaluate them by its value. It will save you space and improve readability of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same Using the Formula.Just make `acc_number__c` as formula field and use the below formula

```
IF(finalize_number__c, Contact.Account.acc_number__c ,''  )
```

In your code you are  writing a SOQL and getting the records in list `con`.You are then forming the updates on this list which in not in trigger.new context.You need to loop through the trigger.new again and then updates the records if you don't want to write a DML.

Another answer by D_k should resolve your issue.

Try this

```
trigger Accnumberupdate3 on contact (before insert ,before update) {
            Set <id> ids = new set<id>();

              for( contact c : trigger.new){
                  if(c.Finalize_Number__c == true){
                   ids.add(c.accountId);
                }
       } 
      Map<Id, Account> mapAcc = new Map<Id, Account>(
    [SELECT id,name from Account where id in :ids]
);

        for (Contact con : trigger.new) {

            if (con.Finalize_Number__c == true) {
                if (mapAcc.containsKey(con.AccountId)) {
                    con.Acc_Number__c = mapAcc.get(con.AccountId).acc_number__c;
                }
            }

        }    

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Everything is fine in your trigger except for:

1.You are instantiating a new contact and assigning it the `acc_number__c` value when you do this you are just creating a contact in the memory.

```
Contact c = new Contact();
```

2. You are looping over accounts (You actually need to loop over the trigger.new list and update it) and assigning the `acc_number__c` without even checking for a related contact record (This could be easily done using a Map. see point 3).

`for (account acc : con) {
    if (c.Finalize_Number__c == true) {
        c.Acc_Number__c = acc.acc_number__c;
    }
}`

3. The result from query should be filled in `Map<Id, Account>`, so that it's easy to identify a Contact's association to an account (via AccountID, please refer to the below code).

Try This:

```
trigger Accnumberupdate3 on contact (before insert , before update) {

    Set <Id> ids = new set<Id>();

    for ( contact c : trigger.new) {
        if (c.Finalize_Number__c) {
            ids.add(c.accountId);
        }
    }

    Map<Id, Account> mapAcc = new Map<Id, Account>(
        [SELECT acc_number__c, Id from Account where Id IN :ids]
    );

    for (Contact con : trigger.new) {
        if (con.Finalize_Number__c) {
            if (mapAcc.containsKey(con.AccountId)) {
                con.Acc_Number__c = mapAcc.get(con.AccountId).acc_number__c;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Code dumps without explanation aren't very useful as answers. Just giving someone the answer doesn't help them learn anything (and I am glad to see that Niknit is interested in learning the reason _why_ things work rather than just taking this and copy/pasting). I've downvoted this answer for now, but if you edit your answer to include an explanation of how this works and how it's different from the code provided by Niknit, I'll retract my downvote.